# Minimizing a Linear Function Over a Halfspace

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming

I'm currently studying convex optimization using Boyd & Vandenberghe's textbook. The exercise problem that I'm having trouble with is the exact same as the one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1811919/how-to-minimize-a-linear-function-over-a-halfspace-efficiently-and-intuitively/1816470). I'll write it out:

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & c^Tx\\ \text{subject to} & a^Tx \le b\end{array}$$

According to the solution manual, this problem is always feasible and the optimal solution is:

$$p* = \begin{cases}\lambda b\quad (c = a\lambda\quad \text{for some}\ \lambda \le 0) \\
-\infty\quad \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

and this is obtained by decomposing vector $c$ into $c = a\lambda + \hat{c}$ where $\hat{c}$ is a vector that is orthogonal to $a$.

I have two question regarding this problem:

1. How do we know this problem is always feasible? I thought that figuring out the feasibility of an LP was as hard as finding the optimal solution itself?
2. Why did the author decompose the vector this way? I guess it did lead to the solution but I'm confused about the motivation and intuition behind it.

Comment: Pick a $2$-vector $a$, draw the half-plane, then draw the level sets of the objective function. The answer will then be obvious.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misinformed, but my thought was that the level sets would need to be parallel to the hyperplane forming the halfspace in order for the vector decomposition to make sense. Can we always be sure that this would be the case?